# How to translate "default(SomeType)" from C# to CIL?

Tags: c#, default, cil

I'm currently working on a problem that involves `System.Reflection.Emit` code generation. I'm trying to figure out what CIL to emit in places where I would use `default(SomeType)` in C#.

I've run a few basic experiments from Visual Studio 11 Beta. [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) shows me the following CIL output for `default(bool)`, `default(string)`, and `default(int?`:

```
.locals init (
    [0] bool                                         V_0,
    [1] string                                       V_1,
    [2] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32> V_2    
)

// bool b = default(bool);
ldc.i4.0
stloc.0

// string s = default(string);
ldnull
stloc.1

// int? ni = default(int?);
ldloca.s V_2
initobj valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>
```

Judging from this, `default(T)` seems to get resolved by the compiler to the most appropriate CIL for the given types.

---

I went on to see what would happen in the more general case, using three generic methods:

```
T CreateStructDefault<T>() where T : struct { return default(T); }
T CreateClassDefault<T>()  where T : class  { return default(T); }
T CreateClassNull<T>()     where T : class  { return null;       }
```

All three methods produce the same CIL method body:

```
.locals init (
    [0] !!T V_0,
    [1] !!T V_1
)

IL_0000: nop    
IL_0001: ldloca.s V_1
IL_0003: initobj !!T
IL_0009: ldloc.1
IL_000a: stloc.0
IL_000b: br.s IL_000d
IL_000d: ldloc.0
IL_000e: ret
```

---

**Question:**

Can I conclude from all this that C#'s `default(SomeType)` corresponds most closely to CIL's…

- `initobj` for non-primitive types (except `string`?)
- `ldc.iX.0` / `ldnull` / etc. for primitive types (plus `string`)?

And why does `CreateClassNull<T>` not just translate to `ldnull`, but to `initobj` instead? After all, `ldnull` was emitted for `string` (which is also a reference type).

Comment: what do you mean with 'primitive' types? There is value types and reference types. I'd expect ldnull with reference types (including string).\

Comment: With "primitive types", I am referring to those natively supported by the CTS (?) -- `bool`, `byte`, `char`, `int`, `float`, `double`, etc. Those that, unlike user-defined value or reference types, are not composites and cannot be broken down to more basic types.

Comment: I note that you must be looking at the debug, unoptimized codegen, given that the compiler has not removed a branch to the next instruction.

Comment: @Eric, I suppose so. The CIL above is from an assembly built with the "Debug" configuration for "AnyCPU".

Comment: @Eric probably will correct me, but aren't so-called primitive types primary related to C# compiler (let's say compiler sugar) but not CTS, CLR or CIL? Also any type can be broken down to Object (but that's definitely another subject to discuss).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Can I conclude from all this that C#'s `default(SomeType)` corresponds most closely to CIL's `initobj` for non-primitive types and `ldc.i4.0`, `ldnull`, etc. for primitive types?

That's a reasonable summary but a better way to think about it is: if the C# compiler would classify `default(T)` as a *compile time constant* then the value of the constant is emitted. That is zero for numeric types, false for bool, and null for any reference type. If it would not be classified as a constant then we must (1) emit a temporary variable, (2) obtain the address of the temporary, (3) initobj that temporary variable via its address and (4) ensure that the temporary's value is on the stack when it is needed.

> why does `CreateClassNull<T>` not just translate to ldnull, but to initobj instead?

Well, let's do it your way and see what happens:

```
... etc
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit P
       extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
  .method private hidebysig static !!T  M<class T>() cil managed
  {
    .maxstack  1
    ldnull
    ret
  } 
  ... etc
```

...

```
D:\>peverify foo.exe

Microsoft (R) .NET Framework PE Verifier.  Version  4.0.30319.17379
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

[IL]: Error: 
[d:\foo.exe : P::M[T]]
[offset 0x00000001]
[found Nullobjref 'NullReference']     
[expected (unboxed) 'T'] 
Unexpected type on the stack.
1 Error(s) Verifying d:\foo.exe
```

That would probably be why we don't do that.

Comment: I don't get it, why would loading a `null` in a reference type (`T: class`) give an error about unboxed `T`?

Comment: +1 Just curious when would the compiler *not* classify `default(T)` as a compile-time constant. My guess would be "when dealing with generics", but I'm curious if there are other cases.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: `default(int?)` is not a compile-time constant. `default(Guid)` is not a compile-time constant. Any not-built-in value type is not a constant.

Comment: @Blindy: Because the method is typed as returning an unboxed T.

Comment: You can have unboxed reference typed objects? I mean that's what `T: class` means, right?

Comment: @Blindy: The CLI definition of "boxing" is different than the C# definition of "boxing"; remember, they have different type systems. This should be expected; the CLI type system is at a lower level than the C# type system. See Partion I section 8.2.4 for a brief overview of the CLI definition of boxing.

Comment: @stakx: The important parts are scattered throughout the specification, but basically the verifier does static type analysis using some rather convoluted rules. These rules distinguish between boxed and unboxed types for type parameters, and the rules do not take into account the fact that the 'class' contrstraint statically proves that the runtime boxed type will be the same as the runtime unboxed type. Basically, the program in question is both valid and typesafe, but the verifier is too simplistic to realize that.

Comment: @Kevin, thanks for that explanation. Perhaps the use of generics in my question made things more complex instead of making them easier.

Comment: @stakx: Yes and no. The use of generics is the only way to make things truely general. If you don't use generics, but use specific types the compiler will generally emit `initobj` for non-"built-in" value-types, `ldnull` for reference types, and specilized code for "built-in" value-types.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's what `default` does. You are correct in deducing it's just syntactic sugar for basically `0` (or equivalents).

Comment: But how does the compiler (or how would I) choose from the different possible ways of encoding that? `ldnull`, `ldfalse`, `ldc.….0` seem obvious enough… but why `initobj`?

Comment: Easy, `Nullable<int>` is a (value) type object, so it gets initialized with `initobj`. Think of it by elimination: you can't load integers into it, value types can't be null (not even `Nullable<>` types), so what's left is initializing it as an empty (default constructor) object.

Comment: And the reason why `string` behaves differently is because it's not a *value* type, its a class. It can hold a null reference, so `default(string)` resolves to `null`, just like `default(Form)` for example.

Comment: Note that my `CreateClassDefault<T>` and `CreateDefaultNull<T>` emit `initobj` also… despite the `where T : class` constraint!

Comment: I'm not sure. I tried both `class` and `class, new()` as constraints in release mode and it still uses `initobj`. At first glance it should just load a `null`. Maybe Eric can give you a better answer since he saw your post!