# How would you emit the default value of a type?

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

I want to implement an interface that automatically clears all local fields, so far I have:

```
// Implement IClearable
dynamicType.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(IClearable));

MethodBuilder clearnMethodBuilder = dynamicType.DefineMethod("Clear", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual, CallingConventions.Standard);
ILGenerator clearMethodILGen = clearnMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

foreach (FieldBuilder localField in fields)
{
    clearMethodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    clearMethodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, localField);
    clearMethodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.??, Profit??);
}

clearMethodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

How do I set the last step to save the default value over the field?

Comment: Is this of interest? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400358/how-to-translate-defaultsometype-from-c-sharp-to-cil

Comment: Yup that helps. Actually, I'm finding out that the correct method might be to emit Activator.CreateInstance(T). Since that will automatically instantiate the default object.

Comment: class or struct? If the latter, you can do `this = new StructName()`.

Comment: Also `Ldfld` in the second step seems illogical.

Comment: Yeah, just realized that. Now I'm just having problems clearing 'Guid'.

Comment: How do you define the default value of some type? It seems you don't mean `default(T)`, but in that case, you need to specify what exactly do you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like:

```
clearMethodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, localField);
clearMethodILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Initobj, localField.FieldType);
```