# default keyword implementation in C#

Tags: c#

I wonder how do I get `0` for `default(int)`. I'd tried to find default value in `Int32` struct with `ILSpy` but I didn't see anything.

Can anyone please explain the mechanic behind the default keyword, how does it work?

Comment: [Default values table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/83fhsxwc.aspx)

Comment: Could I look at this table in .NET framework with ILSpy or Is it in the compiler?

Comment: If you are interested in the low-level aspects of how C# translates `default(…)` to IL, take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400358/how-to-translate-defaultsometype-from-c-sharp-to-cil) and [this detailed answer to it by Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10400998/240733).

Comment: @ogun This is c# language feature. How can you expect this to be in .Net framework code? C# compiler has the knowledge of default values and it just emits the IL.

Comment: @Sriram I've just understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The default keyword returns the default value that is set when you define but not assign a field.

```
public class Program
{
    int someInt;
    string someStr;
}
```

In the example above, `someInt` will be set to `0` and `someStr` will be `null`. Those are the same values that are returned when you use `default(int)` or `default(string)`.

You can't change the behavior in classes because the return value of default will always be `null`. So you might want to look at [structs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx) instead.

Comment: This is only sort-of-correct. The value of `default(T)` solely depends on `T`, and not on some field (nor its type) to which the resulting value gets assigned. That being said, picturing the result of `default` this way at least explains the operator's name. (And one might add that a value-typed field that never gets set explicitly will be implicitly initialized by having all its bits set to 0.)

Comment: @stakx I wasn't trying to imply that it had a relationship with instance fields. Feel free to edit my wording :)